# Spring nested application context "No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I need to export a bunch of JPARepositories in an isolated application context in a spring boot application I then extract and publish the service I need from the isolated application context into the global context.

The configuration class is as follows :

```
@Configuration
@Import({PersistenceAutoConfiguration.class, DaoServicesConfiguration.class})
public class TestApiAutoconfiguration implements InitializingBean {
    private AnnotationConfigApplicationContext myApplicationContext;

    @Autowired
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean primaryEntityManagerFactory;

    @Autowired
    ConfigService configService;

    @Autowired
    FeatureService featureService;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        myApplicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();

        myApplicationContext.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton("entityManagerFactory", primaryEntityManagerFactory.getObject());
        myApplicationContext.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton("configService", configService);
        myApplicationContext.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton("featureService", featureService);

        myApplicationContext.register(TestApiConfiguration.class);
        myApplicationContext.refresh();
    }

    @Bean(name = "/TestApi.json")
    JsonServiceExporter jsonServiceExporter() {
        TestApi testApi = myApplicationContext.getBean(TestApi.class);
        CustomObjectMapper customObjectMapper =    
            myApplicationContext.getBean(CustomObjectMapper.class);

        JsonServiceExporter jsonServiceExporter = new JsonServiceExporter();
        jsonServiceExporter.setService(testApi);
        jsonServiceExporter.setServiceInterface(TestApi.class);
        jsonServiceExporter.setObjectMapper(customObjectMapper);

        return jsonServiceExporter;
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'beanNameHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.payliquid.autoconfigure.TestApiAutoconfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined
```

I'm explicitly publishing the entityManagerFactory so why am I getting this exception ?

Secondly, why is the exception trace mentioned the `WebMvcAutoConfiguration` class ?

Comment: You are registering singletons, then do a refresh which destroys the current beans and recreates a context. Why not simply add the current context as a parent instead of trying to work around it...

Comment: Also looks like a weird contraption which only complicates things and might lead to interesting lifecycle issues... A bean is now suddenly part of multiple contexts...

Comment: If the way I am using refresh is incorrect how am I meant to achieve the pattern above ? The child context has a bean that iterates over the registered repository beans and composes another bean out of them. If I set the parent I'll have to filter out the repositories from the parent.

Comment: No you don't. You just lookup only the repositories from the child, by using the proper method on the context.

Comment: The `refresh()` call is not destroying the registered singletons as I can retrieve them after the call.

Comment: After which call? The refresh one? I still don't see the problem with setting the current context as a parent... Nor do I see or get why you need the contraption you have now.

Answer (score 0):

**The following solution is a workaround. If you know of a better way of achieving it please post an answer**

---

According to some digging around the lifecycle issue regarding the `entityManagerFactory` bean is quite common in programatic configuration of spring data.

I have also encountered the issue when doing standard spring boot, the following pattern needs to be applied to get the right lifecycle sequencing.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(...)
class AConfigurationClass {
   @Bean 
   EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
       //..
   }
}
```

To conform to this pattern I have decided to manually inject the fields as static variables --i.e.,

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = {AcquirerDAO.class})
public class TestApiConfiguration {
    private static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    private static DataSource datasource;

    public static void setEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        entityManagerFactory = emf;
    }

    public static void setDatasource(DataSource ds) {
        datasource = ds;
    }

    @Bean
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        return entityManagerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    DataSource dataSource() {
        return datasource;
    }
 //...
}
```